# WooCommerce email text based on category && shipping zone && payment method

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

I want to display a text in the emails sent to the customer after they place an order based on three variables: product category, shipping zone and payment method.

So for example, I have Category A and Category B, Shipping zone M and Shipping zone N, Payment method X and Payment Method Y.

I want to build a function something like this

```
if (product_category (A) && shipping_zone (M) && payment_method (X)) {
// Display Message 1
    }
else if (product_category (A) && shipping_zone (M) && payment_method (Y)) {
// Display Message 2
    }
... 
And so on for every combination.
```

But I don't know the exact way to check for this variables in the WooCommerce email environment. Can someone please point me in the right direction?